# Java Swing Timer start issue

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer

Using the code provided by helpful user **Stefan** I have edited my own code to emulate his, however I cannot get my timer to start at all. I have tried moving the instance out of the private void and that results in other errors like trying to redefine the timer variable.

```
private Timer timer;        

private void StartStopTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    timer = new Timer(5000,new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        }
    });

    StartStopTimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                timer.start(); AddOneActionPerformed(evt);
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This code has no effect on the timer. It does not start counting

Comment: As mentioned in my example, the timer executes the actionPerformed method after 5 seconds once. If you want the timer to count on every second, you need to set the interval (5000) to 1000 and call timer.setRepeats(true). Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating new timers on every button click (line 3). Make the timer a **field** in your class, initialize it once and only call start and stop in the ActionListeners.

To pause a timer call "stop()", to reset it call "restart()".

**Update**

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

class TimerExample {

   // only one timer per class (field)
   private Timer timer;

   TimerExample() {

    // initialize: counts 5 seconds, calls actionPerformed() and stops
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // handle timer invoked ...
        System.out.println("Now!");
      }      
    });
    timer.setRepeats(true);

    JButton startStopBtn = new JButton("Start / Stop");
    startStopBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                timer.start();
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I hate to bother you, but would you mind giving an example?

Comment: I made a separate java file for your code, but I keep getting the error create class timer in package. I'm not 100% sure what this means. I also get another error saying cannot convert Int to String where the value in milliseconds is

Comment: I modified my code with the code you gave, but now the issue is that the timer will not start